# Scene transition issue, a label loses text Android

Tags: java, android, layout, transition, scene

i have a strange issue. I have an activity and in it 2 scenes which are being changed on comment button click. First scene is a layout with just some text (desc) that is being passed from the before activity and the second scene are comments that are being downloaded with retrofit. Comments work fine but that desc text disappear from the screen when i switch it back from comments even tho that String desc holds the same text. Here is a part of the code, if u need anything else just tell me. Thanks

```
boolean isCommentOpened = false;
rootScene = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_scene);
    commentScene =   Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootScene,R.layout.comments_scene,this);

    textScene =     Scene.getSceneForLayout(rootScene,R.layout.single_data_scene,this);
    fadeTrans = new Fade();

desc = intent.getStringExtra("passedDesc");
TextView titleL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalTitleL);
     descL = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalDescL);


    titleL.setText(title);
    descL.setText(desc);


public void commentClick(View view){

    if (!isCommentOpened){
        int item = Integer.parseInt(itemId);
        View cView =   this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        final Context c = cView.getContext();
        listComments(catId,item,c);
        TransitionManager.go(commentScene,fadeTrans);
        isCommentOpened = true;
    }else {
        Log.i(TAG, "commentClick: "+desc);
        TransitionManager.go(textScene,fadeTrans);
        isCommentOpened = false;
    }

}
```